# Finding the period of a recurring element in an array

Tags: code-golf, array

Given an array `A` of integers, there exists at least one positive integer p such that `A[i] == A[j]` for all `i` and `j` for which `i % p == j % p == 0`. Find the smallest p.

Examples:

- Input array: `[1, _, 1, _, 1, _, 1, _, 1]`. Output: 2
- Input array: `[1, _, _, 1, _, _, 1, _, _]`. Output: 3.
- Input array: `[1, _, _, _, 1, _, _, _, 1]`. Output: 4

Comment: Since the only problem is the lack of objective winning criterion, this seems like a good fit for the [tag:code-golf] tag.

Comment: wha are the `_`?

Comment: I claim Pyth `f!t{%TQ` if this turns out to be code-golf.

Comment: @Jonah It seems to be a number different from A[i] == A[j]

Comment: I take it that `_` stands for any entry that isn't 1? And that the array is zero-indexed?

Comment: I was really hopeful that it would be `i % p == j % p == N` instead, which I think would have been a more interesting challenge

Comment: This could use more clarity on the quantifiers: I assume that "*for all `i` and `j` for which*" should be "*for all `i` and `j` which are valid indexes into `A` and for which*". The examples are missing some important corner cases: the empty array, a one-element array, an array of more than one element without repeats. But most importantly, and the reason that I'm voting to close as unclear, either the test suite or the spec is wrong for languages with 1-based indexing.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 47 bytes

```python
f=lambda l,d=1:f(l,d+1)if~-len({*l[::d]})else d
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIUcnxdbQKk0DSGsbamam1enmpOZpVGvlRFtZpcTWaqbmFKcqpPxPyy9SyFHIzFOI5uKMNtRRMNJRQCFjdbCLA0kkKWMdBROYFAobQ42pjoKZjoK5joKFjoIlUDbWiouzoCgzr0QD6FRNzf8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 43 bytes

```python
f=lambda l,n=1:2>len({*l[::n]})or-~f(l,n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIUcnz9bQysguJzVPo1orJ9rKKi@2VjO/SLcuTQMop22o@T8tv0ghRyEzTyGaizPaUEfBSEcBhYzVwS4OJJGkjHUUTGBSKGwMNaY6CmY6CuY6ChY6CpZAWQUoiDYGqzCG6IGLmiBzIHpNwdqBpClQLtaKi7OgKDOvRAPoI03N/wA)

Assumes the list is non-empy. Outputs `True` as `1`, though for 1 byte this can be fixed by changing `2>` to `1//`.

**44 bytes:**

```python
f=lambda l,n=1:{l[0]}=={*l[::n]}or-~f(l,n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BCsIwEETP7VfssdEVjGmrBvIlIYeKBAsxKaEXKfXX49KqtOgeht15M4ftHv0teJGSVa65X64NOPSKy8HpvRmVGjZOS@nNGOLuaQuCW86SDREctB50nmmOcEBYqcH/PukCCYTyg1b7T6ZCqBGOCCeEM1F4jxZTQsydr1suj7lbTXXSipiRedbF1vcFfcRYegE)

```python
f=lambda l,n=1:l[:-n:n]==l[n::n]or-~f(l,n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY@9DsIwDITn9ik8NsIdQhp@IuVJogxFKKJScKqoCwuvHqwWUCvwcLLvuxs8PqZbIlVKsLG/X649RCQrTXSmJUPe2ujI8JJy@wwNw50UJaQMEQYCV1dOIuwRNurxv8@6Qgqh@6DN/pPRCAeEI8IJ4cwU3uPUnFBL5@t262Pp6rnOqpl5U1djHmhq@CMhygs)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

Assuming this is meant to be [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) for now.

```
mJE€TḢ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/Xy/VR05qQhzsW/f//P9pcR8FCR8FSRwHIMNBRMDQGs0xjAQ)**

Comment: Or `mJE€i1`. Does posting before the question is clarifed get you the win for tiebreaking purposes? I was hesitant to.

Comment: For me it just means I got to post from a computer rather than a mobile. Most wont upvote until the winning criteria is given anyway.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 64 Bytes

A recursive approach.

```
f=lambda x,s=1:s if x[::s].count(x[0])==len(x[::s])else f(x,s+1)
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##dY1RC8IgFIXf@xX3UUlCc70I@yXiwyqlgbmRDuzX2zLbWG1cPFzu@c6xf4Zb53hKprbN/XxtIBIvPLQGohTCq8OlG1xAUVKF69pqhz53rK3XYNCI7xlO/aN1AZBBkhE4Ehi1ysqzvi@KMIx3v@BETaHTOsi/7LwvwGWCkvL@y2gxN@x5tsy1Sp7rcopU63@WyWZ6AQ)

## Python 3, <s>82</s> 81 Bytes

-1 byte thanks to Jakob!

```
lambda x:[x[::i].count(x[0])==len(x[::i])for i in range(1,len(x)+1)].index(1>0)+1
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##bY1BDsIgEEX3nmKWEEkDUjdN6kWQRbWtktShaWqCp0fE2molk/lh5r/59I/xalH6tjz6rrqd6gpcoZwqCqOzs73jSJzimpZl1yB572lrBzBgEIYKLw0RLHp0K6jODNaNI@LAw@j7weAIpCVKMNgxCJpHlVFfG03pZo3NzHyyT2HyQy7vL@yX52zqdRCfrKS5VNr6D5MxKF6wPPXXVMHyTw)

Comment: How about `1>0` instead of `True`?

Comment: For the recursive approach, you need to initialize `s=1` as an optional argument so that the function runs without taking an extra input.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
f!t{%TQ
```

Try it [here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%21t%7B%25TQ&input=%5B3%2C1%2C4%2C3%2C1%2C5%2C3%2C9%2C2%2C3%5D&debug=0). Pyth is at a disadvantage because it uses only printable ASCII; optimally encoded this would be \$7 * \log_{256} 95 = 5.749\$ bytes.

```
f             Find the first positive integer T such that
 !t           there is only one element in
   {          the list obtained by taking unique elements
    %TQ       of every Tth element of the input.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 85 bytes

A lambda from a primitive array type to `int`.

```java
l->{for(int d=0,i;;)for(i=++d;;i+=d){if(i>=l.length)return d;if(l[i]!=l[i-d])break;}}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##XVDLasMwEDw7X7ENBCwii/TdxnWgl0IPPeUYQlEs2VWiyEaSU4Lxt6frR5NSEKt9zKxGs@UHHm3F7lRWG61SSDV3Dj64MlCPgqHpPPd4HQolYI@jcOmtMvlqDdzmjrTIYIuLWOWVZlllUq8Kw96G5EUXLZjCu/Eyl3YBGSQnHS3qrLChMh5EMqMqjklXJ9OpiGM1TQSpVRaqRaKZlib3X8RKX1kDIsa@Xqn1VYIxEmuysZLv4qY5BUGMYvoHUV/KnXSQgJHfcG62coP6msKMwv/Y0D/DvndH4aZLnilE95hdMOczgC8TZNx2VCQ8UHik8IQLunnTKsSfQtgr6kR@wrwX27sZLI/Oyz0rKs9K9NrrX9MZMvfch@OJm8NEjClcnH@1lh8d80UPDbvFhELGeFnq41AT0gpoRnia0w8)

### Ungolfed

```java
l -> {
    for (int d = 0, i; ;)
        for (i = ++d; ; i += d) {
            if (i >= l.length)
                return d;
            if (l[i] != l[i - d])
                break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 bytes

```
@ëX â ÊÉ}f
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=QOtYIOIgysl9Zg==&input=WzEsMiwxLDEsMSwyLDFdCi1R)

Explanation:

```
@       }f    :Get the first integer X which returns 0 from:
 ëX           : Get every Xth item in the input
    â         : Get the unique values of that list
      Ê       : Count how many there are
       É      : Subtract 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Japt, 6 bytes

I think this is right, the spec isn't all that clear. Assumes, as the spec would seem to suggest, that the number we're looking for will always appear first in the array and the `_`s must all be different from that number.

```
ð¶Ug)æ
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8LZVZynm&input=WzcsIDgsIDksIDcsIDAsIDEzLCA3LCA1XQ==)

```
           :Implicit input of array U
ð          :0-based indices of elements
 ¥         :  Equal to
  Ug       :  First element of U
    )      :End indexing
     æ     :First truthy (non-zero) element
```

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 82 bytes

```powershell
(($a=$args)|%{($i++)}|?{"$a"-match"^(\d+)(( -?\d+){$_} \1)*( -?\d+){0,$_}$"})[0]+1
```

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

(($a=$args)|%{($i++)}|?{"$a"-match"^(\d+)(( -?\d+){$_} \1)*( -?\d+){0,$_}$"})[0]+1

}

@(
    ,(1 , 1,1,1,1,1)
    ,(2 , 1,-2,1,3,1,-4,1,5)
    ,(2 , 1,-2,1,3,1,-4,1,5,1)
    ,(3 , 1,-2,1,1,3, 4,1,5,1)  # 1 may be in place '_'
    ,(4 , 1,-2,3,4,1, 5,1,6,1)
    ,(5 , 1,2,3,4,5,1)
) | % {
    $expected, $a = $_
    $result = &$f @a
    "$($result-eq$expected): $result"

}
```

Explanation:

`Regexp` match on `array.toString()` which equivalent `array.join(' ')`.